# MySQL - Erro ao realizar INSERT com FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá, ao realizar uma inserção no banco de dados o MySQL retorna o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zabbix`.`tb_hosts`, CONSTRAINT `tb_hosts_ibfk_1` FO
REIGN KEY (`fk_hostname_grupo`) REFERENCES `tb_grupos` (`hostname_grupo`))
```

Qual o erro ? Obrigado desde já!

Código usado:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_grupos(
  id_grupo int(50) NOT NULL,
  hostname_grupo varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE tb_hosts (
  id_host int(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  hostname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  fk_hostname_grupo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(hostname_grupo));

  CREATE TABLE tb_monitoramento (
  problemas varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tempo int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  fk2_hostname_grupo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk2_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(hostname_grupo));

CREATE TABLE tb_eventos (
  id_evento int(50) NOT NULL,
  eventos varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  tempo int(50) NOT NULL,
  trigger_or_network int(3) NOT NULL,
  ok_or_problema_or_desconhecido int(3) NOT NULL,
  fk3_hostname_grupo varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk3_hostname_grupo) REFERENCES tb_grupos(hostname_grupo));

  insert into tb_grupos values("2","usergroup");
  insert into tb_hosts values("3","user", 1);
```

Comment: Vai me desculpar mas esse log de erro não condiz com esse código. [Olhe aqui](https://paiza.io/projects/e/hajMMAUn7VOOWtG8mNfPEQ) não apresenta erro.

Comment: sim, porém quando executo no MySQL instalado em minha máquina apresenta erro, estou utilizando Deepin 15.10, pode ser algum bug na distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando `hostname_grupo` como PK, e no `insert` está adicionando um item na `tb_hosts.hostname` cujo valor não existe na tabela referenciada.

Comment: @userlimer para separar um caso do outro, crie uma outra perguntar para isso. Isso ajuda quem futuramente tiver o mesmo problema. :)

Comment: beleza obrigado!

Comment: E se o problema tiver sido esse, sinalize como resposta. Se não, poste a resposta e depois sinalize como correta. :)